# Get information from Toggle switch in Django

Tags: python, html, django, frontend

I have a panel to manage users and for each user there is a toggle switch to activate and deactivate
My problem is that I don't know how to send the Toggle switch status to Django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zxhN.png)

I tried to use the forms, but unfortunately I did not succeed

Comment: please mention the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.